# How can i show from 2 tables even in the second is null?

Tags: sql

How can i show data from 2 tables even in the second table is null?
Here is my code, but i got only where  value is not null!

```
SELECT ot.term as term1, tt.term as term2 
FROM translation t, original_language ol, original_term ot 
LEFT JOIN translate_term tt ON tt.id = ot.id, translate_language tl 
WHERE t.fk_original_labguage_id = ol.id 
AND ol.id = ot.fk_original_language_id 
AND t.fk_translation_labguage_id = tl.id 
AND tt.fk_translate_language_id = tl.id
```

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: Your query references more than two tables... which table contains the master data? What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Without table definition, no one knows what you want.  I tried to convert to `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT ot.term as term1, tt.term as term2 
FROM translation t
JOIN original_language ol ON t.fk_original_labguage_id = ol.id 
JOIN original_term ot ol.id = ot.fk_original_language_id 
LEFT JOIN translate_term tt ON tt.id = ot.id, translate_language tl AND t.fk_translation_labguage_id = tl.id AND tt.fk_translate_language_id = tl.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Then the condition for the `LEFT JOIN` goes in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT ot.term as term1, tt.term as term2 
FROM translation t JOIN
     original_language ol
     ON t.fk_original_labguage_id = ol.id JOIN
     original_term ot 
     ON ol.id = ot.fk_original_language_id LEFT JOIN
     translate_term tt
     ON tt.id = ot.id ;
```

I removed the part of the query referring to languages, because you are not selecting any columns related to language.